# Are free and open source templates, themes, self content management systems replacing the need of web designers?

Tags: css, xhtml

Are free and open source  **[templates](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=free+css+templates&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)**, **[themes](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=w2h&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=free+wordpress+themes&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)**, self **[content management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_content_management_system)** replacing the need of web designers?

You can find templates online for pretty much anything these days. There are html and css templates, templates for Wordpress, all sorts of different cms templates, e-ecommerce templates, etc. Many of these are pretty cheap and some are even free, so where do web designers fit into this picture? I’ve had many clients and potential customers ask why they should use my services instead of just buying a cheap template. Are web designers being replaced?

Are they all forcing web designers to reduce prices of service?

Comment: This is a silly question, who makes those free templates, themes, and CMS

Comment: Is a "silly question" one that makes jokes?

Answer (score 9):

No. Where does the free templates come from?

Answer (score 2):

No, because a human web designer can tailor a project for a specific need, whereas a template will always have restrictions. A web designer can make something *unique* that stands out from the crowd.

I think that templates and other similar systems make it easier for a potential client to make an uninformed, rash decision that may save them money up front, but will eventually be something they regret.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, they reduce the burden of the designer so they don't have to do as much work. In some cases you can directly implement one of the ready available templates, put the client's data and its all good. 
 But most of the times you'll end up modifying the design to the clients requirement(considering the client accepts a ready-made template). Here you'll need design skills. 
 Also consider even though there are a large number of templates available, there are finite and if you're looking for something very specific - a template will just not cut it.
So weather you work alone or at a firm - Design skills and Web Designers are essential and will remain so.

Answer (score 0):

If your potential customers are okay with the current selection of open source templates, designs and CMSs, go for it.

You still need to customize and deliver as a web designer/programmer. Does the open source projects offer free support? I doubt. People still need someone to do the job as well.

Web designers are not being replaced. If your work is worse than open source web designers and you don't offer any customization or support, you might be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be a need for web designers.  As Letseatfood said, a designer can custom tailor to fit a project to a client's need.  There are also so many services offering "Do It Yourself" websites, but they can't replace designers.  Some small businesses might go with a template or a DIY, but the final product will not be as good as a custom built website.

And also, if you aren't finding enough clients for custom websites, you can always try making templates to sell, haha!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your site to look and act like everyone else's, then you don't need a web designer. However, if your site has the same "product" as everyone else, how do you differentiate yourself aside from price?

Free template only bring you up to the same level as everyone else. You need your own designers to give you the edge.